# Alamofire - serializing generic response objects to model from JSON without forced unwrap

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to serialize as request response (in the form of JSON) to a model - the JSON maybe missing some properties sometimes hence I've tried to use the method [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to protect against that.

However, the model is throwing the classic `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` from the model - where the model has tried to force unwrap a non-optional value on the init call from the responseObject JSON - but because it doesn't exist, the force unwrap fails.

What is the best solution for handling this from Alamofire?

Model:

```
final public class User: ResponseObjectSerializable {
    let username: String
    let name: String

    public init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        self.username = representation.valueForKeyPath("username") as! String
        self.name = representation.valueForKeyPath("name") as! String
    }
}
```

Alamofire request extension:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                response = response,
                responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Client request:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
        .validate()
        .responseObject { (response: Response<User, NSError>) in
          switch response.result {
            case .Success(let user):

                completionHandler(user, nil)

          case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")

                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
        return self
```

Comment: did you try double unwrapping like this **variableName!!** ?

Comment: I'm afraid this just throws a `Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10e6e5378) to 'NSString' (0x10dd52b20).` and breaks. Using the following code: `self.username = (representation.valueForKeyPath("username") as? String)!`

Comment: Note the `representation.valueForKeyPath("username")!! ?` threw an error expecting a statement after the ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `User` class with a failable initializer, but you don't appear to be using it.

Here's a simple version of what I'm thinking:

```
class User {
let firstName: String

init?(name: String?) {
    guard let name = name else {
        self.firstName = "" // trash value needed until swift 2.2
        return nil
    }
    self.firstName = name
}
}
```